# Override module in virtualenv with local directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-module

I'm rather new to python and am running into an issue that I can't get past. I have a module A that depends on module B. Normally, A downloads B and stores it with the rest of the eggs in my virtualenv site-packages. Now, I have a local version of B that I want to use instead of this downloaded version of B but no matter what I seem to do, A still uses the B in its site packages and not the one that I specify in my PYTHONPATH.

I know that my local B is set up right because I can use it just fine if I add it to my PYTHONPATH and I'm not using virtualenv.

If I open up ipython with the local B prepended to PYTHONPATH, I see that my sys.path lists the site-packages version first, *then* the directory in my PYTHONPATH. If I do something hacky like reverse the order of sys.path and attempt to load B, it *still* uses the B from site-packages. The only way I've found to get around this is to create a sym link from the B in my site-packages to my local B and remove all the *.pyc files in my local B. There just has to be a better way to do this... any help would be awesome. Thank you!

I'm not sure this will matter but for reference I'm using the following versions of stuff:

- virtualenv 12.1.1
- python 2.7
- modules A and B are internal libraries at my company
- Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: Can you just uninstall the remote version and `pip install -e` the local?

Comment: You need to uninstall package B (from your site-packages) and then make sure your local copy of B is accessible somewhere in (importable from) your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @tzaman That works pretty well, actually. I don't even have to redo the pip install when I make changes to the local version. I am still hoping for an answer to why the PYTHONPATH just doesn't work, but this is workable solution for my task at hand. Thanks!

Comment: @LizBennett awesome! I've posted it as an answer with some more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working on a pair of related projects where one depends on the other, you can just uninstall the "remote" version and use `pip install -e` to install it from your local copy in [editable mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs).

This will let your dependent project see it, and automatically see changes to the upstream project without needing any extra work.

Comment: The only problem I had with this was that module A depends on package C version 1.3.6, whereas module B also depends on package C, but version 1.3.3. When I am in the virtualenv for working on module A and I do pip install -e /path/to/B, it tries to build module B with the wrong version of C, i.e. 1.3.6 when B needs 1.3.3. For this it was fine just upgrading B's dependency, but that might not always be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Python will always look in your install dir (site-packages) for packages before looking in your current directory. If/When it finds a package in the install dir, it stops looking.

You can reference your local copy explicitly if that's what you want to do.

```
from . import ModuleB
from .. import ModuleB
#etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm surprised that there is no way to override this behavior. It seems that the only way to load my local version (without using the syntax you suggested) is to actually remove what is in site-packages. As someone from java land, it's odd to go from having complete control over the order of libraries being loaded to not really having control.